# find and replace percent symbol within string with back slash in ruby?

Tags: ruby, gsub, ruby-1.8.7

I tried this :

```
irb(main):125:0> a = "ab%c"
=> "ab%c"
irb(main):126:0> a.gsub("%", '\\')
=> "ab\\c"
irb(main):127:0>
```

whereas expected output is:

```
ab\c
```

it did not work.

Thanks in advance.

Update: ruby version

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: It did work. Why do you claim it didn't? `puts a.gsub('%', '\\') # => ab\c`.

Comment: It didn't work for me in ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Why do you say it didn't? Your console output is correct.

Comment: Did you bother reading my comment and shivam's answer?

Comment: sorry, but it isen't. expected output is ab\c whereas i am getting ab\\c.

Comment: Again: Did you bother reading my comment and shivam's answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot. wasn't looking at it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = "ab%c"
a.gsub!("%", '\\')  
#=> "ab\\c"
puts a
# ab\c
```

in `"ab\\c"` backslash `\` is being escaped using character `\`. 
you can verify this with `puts`